# Linux timeout if no output

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

In my script I want to execute a command which connects to a remote server and may take very long time due to a bad network connection. So I want it to time out and be killed after 60 seconds.  However there are cases where it just starts working at the 59th second and is killed shortly with truncated output (unfinished task).

I am using GNU timeout which only accepts a time value, and kills the process after that time passes. What I am expecting is a tool that times out and kills a process only if:

1. That time passes
2. There is NO output from that process.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you may want to approach the problem differently. Assuming you're connecting to the remote server via SSH, you should consider launching the process in such a way that the SSH connection can hang up normally and the process continue to execute. It would ultimately look something like:

```
nohup script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This uses the `nohup` command to execute `script.sh` in a way that is immune to hang-ups, redirecting STDIN/STDOUT to the discard bin (/dev/null) and then backgrounding the process. This should release the TTY used for the initial connection and allow the process to continue to run in the background even after the session (and TTY) are closed.